Undefined при расчете процента в калькуляторе на js
Я пишу для петпроекта калькулятор. При подсчете процента у меня пишет undefind. При введении в основное поле(displayScreen) вводятся первое число - операция - второе число, первое число уходит в numA, второе в numB, результат отражается в displayResult.  Все операции, кроме процентов, правильно считаются. При подсчете процентов в numA идет просто число, в numB идет numB.value = (+numA.value * +numB.value) / 100. При нажатии равно в displayResult получаю undefined. Что пошло не так?
Полный код с html, css, js тут на codepen
digits.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      //нажата кнопка калькулятора All Clear / C
      // if (e.target.classList.contains("#clearAll")) return;

      let digitValue = +digits[i].value;

      displayScreen.value += digitValue;

      if (numA.value !== NaN && sign === "") {
        numA.value = displayScreen.value;
      } else if (numA.value !== "" && sign !== "") {
        numB.value += +digitValue;
      }

      console.log(+numA.value);
      console.log(typeof +numA.value);
      console.log(+numB.value);
      console.log(typeof +numB.value);
    });
  });

  op.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (operator.includes(item.value)) {
        sign = item.value;
        displayScreen.value += item.value;
        finish = true;
        console.log(sign);
      }
      `if (sign === "%") {
        percent();
      }`
    });
  });

  `function percent() {
    numB.value = (+numA.value * +numB.value) / 100;
    console.log(+numB.value);
    console.log(typeof +numB.value);
  }`

  //выполнение вычислений
  let result;

  function calc() {
    switch (sign) {
      case "+":
        result = +numA.value + +numB.value;
        console.log(+numB.value);
        console.log(typeof +numB.value);
        break;
      case "-":
        result = +numA.value - +numB.value;
        // console.log(result);
        break;
      case "*":
        result = +numA.value * +numB.value;
        // console.log(result);
        break;
      case "/":
        result = +numA.value / +numB.value;
        // console.log(result);
        break;
      case "^":
        result = Math.pow(+numA.value, +numB.value);
        // console.log(result);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    
    displayResult.value = result;
    numA.value = "";
    numB.value = "";
    console.log(+numB.value);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(typeof result);
    console.log(typeof displayResult.value);

  }

  document.querySelector(".calc").addEventListener("click", calc);```


Во-первых, код должен быть не полный, а [mcve], а во-вторых, он должен быть не на codepen, а прямо в тексте вопроса без сторонних ссылок

А в-третьих, у вас sign равен "%", из чего следует, что внутри функции calc переменная result никогда не инициализируется

Спасибо. в будущем буду минимизировать. В коде sign % привяжу к  calc или решу через другую функцию

Вы забыли case для % добавить
case "%":
  result = +numA.value * (+numB.value/100);
break;

Я добавил и всё работает. 10 % 100 вывело 10

Выражения наподобие 200 + 50% сильно обижаются на ваше решение

Да согласен, не сразу понял условие
